# Replace missing values with mean for subsets of dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame titled final_project_data with the following structure. It includes 17 columns with data that corresponds to the county/ State and years. For example, Baldwin county in Alabama in 2006 had a population of 69162, an unemployment rate of 4.2% etc.

```
ID          County       State       Population   Year    Ump.Rate Fertility  
<dbl>       <chr>        <chr>       <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1003    Baldwin County   Alabama     69162        2006     4.2     88
1015    Calhoun County   Alabama     112903       2006     2.4     na
1043    Baldwin County   Alabama     na           2007     1.9     71
1049    Calhoun County   Alabama     68014        2007     na      90
1050    CountyY          Alaska      2757         2006     3.9     na
1070    CountyZ          Alaska      11000        2006     7.8     95
1081    CountyY          Alaska      na           2007     6.5     70
1082    CountyZ          Alaska      67514        2007     4.5     60
```

There are a number of columns with missing values in them, which I am trying to replace with the mean for the given State and Year. I am running into issues trying to loop over each column with missing values and then each subset of years and rows to fill in the missing values with the mean. The code I have thus far is below:

```
#get list of unique states
states <- unique(final_project_data$State)
#get list of columns with na in them - we will use this to impute missing 
values
list_na <- colnames(final_project_data)[ apply(final_project_data, 2, anyNA) ]

list_na
#create a place to hold the missing values
average_missing <- c()

#Loop through each state to impute the missing values with the mean
for(i in 1:length(states)){
 average_missing <- apply(final_project_data[which(final_project_data$State == states[i]),colnames(final_project_data) %in% list_na], 2, mean, na.rm =  TRUE) 
 }
average_missing
```

However, when I run the above bit of code, I only get one set of values for each of the columns with missing values, not for a different value for every state. I am also not sure how to extend this to include years. Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You are saying you need to replace NA with mean of Year and State. I'm not getting it. How do we even calculate mean  of Year and State. These are non numbers.

Comment: You are right, sorry, my question was not clear. The columns such as ump.Rate, fertility etc. have na values in them. I want to replace those na's with the mean value for the State and Year to which the county belongs. For example, Calhoun County in Alabama is missing the ump.rate in 2007. I want to replace the na with the average ump. rate in Alabama in 2007. I have edited my question, and apologize for the bad phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

In a for loop:

```
dt <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1003, 1015, 1043, 1049, 1050, 1070, 1081, 1082, NA, NA),
  State = c(rep("Alabama", 4), rep("Alaska", 4), "Alabama", "Alaska"),
  Population = c(sample(10000:100000, 8, replace = T), NA, NA),
  Year = c(2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2006),
  Unemployment = c(sample(1:5, 8, replace = T), NA, NA)
)

# index through each row in data frame
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){

# if Population variable is NA
  if(is.na(dt$Population[i]) == T){ 

# calculate mean from all Population variables with the same State and Year as index
    dt$Population[i] <- mean(dt$Population[which(dt$State == dt$State[i] & dt$Year == dt$Year[i])], na.rm = T)
  }

# repeat for Unemployment variable
  if(is.na(dt$Unemployment[i]) == T){ 
    dt$Unemployment[i] <- mean(dt$Unemployment[which(dt$State == dt$State[i] & dt$Year == dt$Year[i])], na.rm = T)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` version without a loop. Just add all the columns you want to transform insided `vars()`:

```
your_data %>%
  group_by(State, Year) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Population, Ump.Rate, Fertility),
            ~ ifelse(is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = TRUE), .))
```